# Java Open in Browser isn't working (in Chrome only)

Tags: java

This code couldn't be any simpler. However, it does nothing (other than output my print statement).

I'm in a desktop Java application with Chrome set as the default browser.

What am I missing? Thanks!

```
    String url = "https://www.google.com/";
    try {
         if (java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
             System.out.println("yes");
         else System.out.println("no"); 
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
        System.out.println("here");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("exception thrown");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done");
```

My exact output is this:

> yes
> here
> done

EDIT: I switched my default browser from Chrome to Firefox, and now it works. Why won't Chrome respond to this?

Comment: Are you getting any other kinds of exception?  `IOException` isn't the only one that it would throw.

Comment: None that I can see. My console is clean, and I'm not crashing or anything.

Comment: Do you see the "here" line at least?  You said your console was clean; this would imply it was *really* clean.

Comment: Are you sure that your platform supports getDesktop()? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop%28%29

Comment: This code ran in my environment JRE1.8, where default browser is firefox.

Comment: Adding to rogue_js's comment, check `Desktop.isDesktopSupported();`.

Comment: @usr55410 Can you confirm that no code at a higher level than this is swallowing an exception? The snippet you've posted does not convince us that an exception was not thrown, as it could be being called in a block that catches and ignores any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited code. Hopefully this will answer any questions.

Comment: The same code also works in Safari in Mac OS X. No issues found.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI)` was not working for Google Chrome, but worked fine with Firefox as default browser.

I re installed Chrome and selected "Set as default browser" using [Google installer](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).

Then, I ran a test and Chrome worked. I debugged and Chrome didn't worked.

**Conclusion:** when using `Run`, Chrome works. When using `Debug`, Chrome does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with the Desktop.getDesktop.browse(URI),
Tried a multiple alternatives such as "rundll32", "url.dll","FileProtocolHandler" , however all seem to be resulting in same issue (code gets executed , but no action),

The issue got resolved when I ran my application as standalone instead of running as service. Somehow when the application is ran as service, windows is not allowing any file opening protocols.

P.S : Could not find a promising solution for service so far.